# mysql table unaligned in console output when using UTF8

Tags: utf-8, console, mysql

I like to use `mysql` client. But when using UTF-8, the tables on the console are unaligned:

```
> set names utf8;
> [some query]
+--------+---------+---------------------------------+-----------------------------+----------+---------+-----------+-------+---------+-----------+
| RuleId | TaxonId | Note                            | NoteSci                     | MinCount | DayFrom | MonthFrom | DayTo | MonthTo | ExtraNote |
+--------+---------+---------------------------------+-----------------------------+----------+---------+-----------+-------+---------+-----------+
|    722 |   10090 | sedmihlásek malý              | Hippolais caligata          |        1 |       1 |         1 |    31 |      12 | NULL      |
|    727 |   10059 | Anseranas semipalmata           | husovec strakatý           |        1 |       1 |         1 |    31 |      12 | NULL      |
|    728 |   10062 | Cygnus atratus                  | labuť černá              |        1 |       1 |         1 |    31 |      12 | NULL      |
|    729 |   10094 | Anser cygnoides                 | husa labutí                |        1 |       1 |         1 |    31 |      12 | NULL      |
|    730 |   10063 | Tadorna cana                    | husice šedohlavá          |        1 |       1 |         1 |    31 |      12 | NULL      |
|    731 |   10031 | Cairina moschata f. domestica   | pižmovka domácí          |       20 |       1 |         1 |    31 |      12 | NULL      |
|    732 |   10088 | Cairina scutulata               | pižmovka bělokřídlá    |        1 |       1 |         1 |    31 |      12 | NULL      |
|    733 |   10087 | Anas sibilatrix                 | hvízdák chilský          |        1 |       1 |         1 |    31 |      12 | NULL      |
|    734 |   10077 | Anas platyrhynchos f. domestica | kachna domácí             |     1000 |       1 |         1 |    31 |      12 | NULL      |
|    735 |   10086 | Anas hottentota                 | čírka hottentotská       |        1 |       1 |         1 |    31 |      12 | NULL      |
|
```

This is apparently because mysql client will compute the widths of the columns using string length which doesn't take UTF-8 characters into account - so then there is exactly one space missing for each accented character (because these actually take two bytes).

Do you know possible workaround for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run your `mysql` client with [charset](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_default-character-set) option:

```
mysql -uUSER -p DATABASE --default-character-set=utf8
```

(`USER` and `DATABASE` should be replaced with actual credentials data)

Comment: it is strange that only this works - none of the variables in `show variables` has this effect! I tried to `set @@` them all to `utf8` but with no effect!

Comment: Why strange? Variables (in general) has nothing to do with _client_ - they all are _server_ variables. Therefore, to change client behavior - you need to apply _client_ options

Comment: nope, many of the variables affect how the data are displayed by the client (in which character set). I guess these are called *connection* variables, not all of them are *server* variables.

Comment: Yes, that's why I've added _in general_

Comment: so you see, it is strange that some of the client behaviour is handled by the variables and some is not...